# How to make a slideshow of a texture image in Unity 5

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a visual city project and I've got a question which is running on my head! Basically I have made a simple advertisment board and I added a texture to it which is a poster. My question is that ,how can I be able to make this board changing it's texture after a period of time to another texture! I mean the board would be like a slideshow and the textures would be changeable to another. So it would not be static anymore. Here's the image of the board:

[image: print screen]

So if you know how to do this, please let me know and give some guidelines.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could prepare a `List<Texture2D>` of textures you want to be in your slideshow and then assign a script to your advertisement board, that assigns a new `Texture2D` from that `List` to the boards `Material` when a specific amount of time has passed.

For counting time you can accumulate `Time.deltaTime` in your `Update` function for example.

For setting the texture of the material you can use `Material.SetTexture` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetTexture.html) if I am not mistaken.